# Parse text by uppercase in R

Tags: r, text, text-mining, uppercase

I have many large text files with the following basic composition:

```
text<-"this is a speech text. FIRST PERSON: hi all, thank you for coming. SECOND PERSON: thank you for inviting us"
```

As you can see, it is composed of: 1) Random text, 2) Person in uppercase, 3) Speech.

I've managed to separate in a list all the words using:

```
textw<-unlist(strsplit(text," "))
```

I then find all the position of the words which are uppercase:

```
grep(pattern = "^[[:upper:]]*$",x = textw)
```

And I have separated the names of persons into a vector;

```
upperv<-textw[grep(pattern = "^[[:upper:]]*$",x = textw)]
```

The desired outcome would be a data frame or table like this:

```
Result<-data.frame(person=c(" ","FIRST PERSON","SECOND PERSON"),
         message=c("this is a speech test.","hi all, thank you for coming.","thank you for inviting us"))

Result
         person                       message
1                      this is a speech test.
2  FIRST PERSON hi all, thank you for coming.
3 SECOND PERSON     thank you for inviting us
```

I'm having trouble "linking" each message to it's author.

Also be noted: there are uppercase words which are NOT an author, for example "I". How could I specify a separation only where 2 or more uppercase words are next to each other?

In other words, if position 2 and 3 are upper case, then place as message everything from position 4 until next occurrence of double uppercases.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: On the last question, you can add a delimiter {2} after :upper: so that there must be at least two upper case letters in a row (avoiding the "I" problem at least.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one approach using the **stringi** package:

```
text <- "this is a speech text. FIRST PERSON: hi all, thank you for coming. SECOND PERSON: thank you for inviting us"

library(stringi)
txt <- unlist(stri_split_regex(text, "(?<![A-Z]{2,1000})\\s+(?=[A-Z]{2,1000})"))

data.frame(
    person = stri_extract_first_regex(txt, "[A-Z ]+(?=(:\\s))"),
    message = stri_replace_first_regex(txt, "[A-Z ]+:\\s+", "")
)


##          person                       message
## 1          <NA>        this is a speech text.
## 2  FIRST PERSON hi all, thank you for coming.
## 3 SECOND PERSON     thank you for inviting us
```

Comment: I'm sure one of the regex wizards here will have a more succinct approach.

Comment: The `{2,1000}` is a bit dirty

Comment: `[A-Z]{2,1000}` might be replaced by: `[A-Z][A-Z]+` which would allow person identifiers of two up to infinite.

Comment: @petermeissner can you give a example? In R that says invalid pattern with `stri_split_regex` or `strsplit`

Comment: see my answer for an example (you could replace `[[:upper:]]` with `[A-Z]`)

Answer (score 2):

**Basic Approach**

1) to get the text I will follow Tyler Rinkers approach of splitting the text by a sequence of one and more (`+`) ONLY UPPER CASE LETTERS (`[[:upper:]]`) that might also entail spaces and colons (`[ [:upper:]:]`): `"[[:upper:]]+[ [:upper:]:]+"`

2) to extract the persons speaking the nearly the same regex is used (not allowing colons anymore): `"[[:upper:]]+[ [:upper:]]+"` (again, the basic idea is stolen from Tyler Rinker)

**stringr**

```
require(stringr)

text <- "this is a speech text. FIRST PERSON: hi all, thank you for coming. SECOND PERSON: thank you for inviting us"

data.frame (
    person  = c( NA,
                 unlist(str_extract_all(text, "[[:upper:]]+[ [:upper:]]+"))
                ),
    message = unlist(str_split(text, "[[:upper:]]+[ [:upper:]:]+"))
    )

##          person                        message
## 1          <NA>        this is a speech text. 
## 2  FIRST PERSON hi all, thank you for coming. 
## 3 SECOND PERSON      thank you for inviting us
```

**stringi**

```
require(stringi)

text <- "this is a speech text. FIRST PERSON: hi all, thank you for coming. SECOND PERSON: thank you for inviting us"

data.frame (
    person  = c( NA,
                 unlist(stri_extract_all(text, regex="[[:upper:]]+[ [:upper:]]+"))
                ),
    message = unlist(stri_split(text, regex="[[:upper:]]+[ [:upper:]:]+"))
    )

##          person                        message
## 1          <NA>        this is a speech text. 
## 2  FIRST PERSON hi all, thank you for coming. 
## 3 SECOND PERSON      thank you for inviting us
```

**Hints (that reflect my preferences rather than rules)**

1) I would prefer `"[A-Z]+"` over `"[A-Z]{1,1000}"` because in the first case on does not have to decide what might actually be a reasonable number to put in.

2) I would prefer `"[[:upper:]]"` over `"[A-Z]"` because the former works like this ...

```
str_extract("Á", "[[:upper:]]")
## [1] "Á"
```

... while the latter works like this ...

```
str_extract("Á", "[A-Z]")
## [1] NA
```

... in case of special character.